# Why multiple arguments in scanf() function in c crash the app?

Tags: c, arrays, crash, scanf

I cant really understand if its the syntax of the following scanf()

The purpose of this program is to read math inputs like:
6x+7y+8z=2 (x3 times)
and then output an array that holds the numerical values of the input.

After successfully giving the input the application crashes
Although the compiler shows no error or warning of any kind

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()  
{
    int number[3][4],i,j;
    char vch[3][4];

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
scanf("%d%c%d%c%d%c%c%d",&number[i][0],&vch[i][0],&number[i][1],&vch[i][1],&number[i][2],&vch[i][2],&vch[i][3],&number[i][3]);
printf("\n");
}
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        printf("%d",number[i][j]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show the exact input you used; this code worked fine for me.

Comment: btw + or - x doesnt work

Comment: this absolutly won't work. What are you trying to do?

Comment: better you can try to take this as a string and split up the numbers.

Comment: i made a mistake the exact input was 3x+6y+7z=2<enter>

Comment: You are not reading x and y in your expression - or maybe I misunderstood whether you wanted to "consume" the operators rather than treat them as the sign of the number that follows. See my code snippet.

Comment: My intention is the +/- to be part of the integer inside the array cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the equation you are showing, you really need to read two characters between the first sets of numbers (instead of one).  So you would want to do

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int number[3][4],i,j;
    char vch[3][6];

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
printf("enter equation %d:\n", i);
scanf("%d %c %c %d %c %c %d %c %c %d",&number[i][0], &vch[i][0], &vch[i][1], \
                                      &number[i][1], &vch[i][2], &vch[i][3], \
                                      &number[i][2], &vch[i][4], &vch[i][5], \
                                      &number[i][3]);
}
for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        printf("%4d ",number[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

output:

```
enter equation 0:
2x+3y+4z=0
enter equation 1:
2x+5y+10z=-15
enter equation 2:
5x+7y+9z=3
   2    3    4    0 
   2    5   10  -15 
   5    7    9    3
```

**EDIT** an improved program that does not use `scanf` and handles various other inputs could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int interpret(char* s) {
  // interpret the string as a number
  // if there is only a sign, return +1 or -1 as appropriate

  int it;
  if(sscanf(s, "%d", &it) == 1) return it;
  // look for just a sign with no number
  if( strstr(s, "-") > 0) return -1;
  return 1;
}

void squeezeWhite(char* s) {
  // remove all spaces
  char *t = s;
  int ii = 0;
  while(*t !='\0') {
    if (*t != ' ') s[ii++] = *t;
    t++;
  }
  s[ii] = '\0';
}

void tokenize(char *buf, int *arr) {
  char *temp;
  int it;
  squeezeWhite(buf);
  temp = strtok(buf, "xyz");
  // handle the case of nothing in front of x:
  if(temp == buf + 1) {
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = interpret(temp);
  }
  else {
    arr[0] = interpret(temp);
    temp = strtok(NULL, "xyz");
    arr[1] = interpret(temp);
  }
  temp = strtok(NULL, "xyz");
  arr[2] = interpret(temp);
  temp = strtok(NULL, "=");
  arr[3] = interpret(temp);
}

int main()
{
    int number[3][4],i,j;
    char vch[3][6];
    char buffer[100];

  for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    printf("enter equation %d:\n", i);
    fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
    tokenize(buffer, number[i]);
  }
  for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
      printf("%4d ",number[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Example of input/output:

```
enter equation 0:
-x+y+z=1
enter equation 1:
2x + 3 y + 4 z = 7
enter equation 2:
+2x+2y+2z=+2
  -1    1    1    1 
   2    3    4    7 
   2    2    2    2
```

As you can see it handles coefficients gracefully, even if there are no numbers (just + or - signs). The basic idea I am showing here - to process the input in steps - is a good idea when your user may not conform to your input specification. It is much more robust than reading `scanf`, which will fall at the first hurdle. It did involve writing a few "helper functions". That's usually how it works...

Comment: I thought +/- signs were read as a part of the signed integer's sign<br>Assumption:int is signed

Comment: Yes - I had assumed your equations could be "any operators" and that you wanted to read the operator. If these are always linear operators, you don't need that nicety.  By the way, how would you want to handle `x + 2y + z = 0`? Your code (and mine) will crash… `scanf` is a terribly fragile function. Would you consider using something more robust (e.g. `strtok`)?

Comment: Your expression should be handle like #undefined (+1x) would work theoretically and +2 +1 0 inside numbers cells in order and inside vchr cells x y z = (those will be printed later)                                                    str functions read those data as characters and i need +/- ints to be handled in certain simple calculations. (not shown here)

Comment: Let me play around for a minute… I'll get back to you.

Comment: Glad to hear it! There is some more information in the update I just posted. Maybe there's a useful snippet in there for you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
scanf("%d %c %c %d %c %c %d %c %c %d",&number[i][0],&vch[i][0],&vch[i][1] &number[i][1],&vch[i][2],&vch[i][3],&number[i][2],&vch[i][4],&vch[i][5],&number[i][3]);
```

with an extra space before `%c` to eat up the newline character `\n` left behind by the previous `scanf`.